# Array returns different LUA

Tags: arrays, lua

I have a problem with my array. I initially put some values in it, but when i tried to display the content of the array by making another loop that would print the values, it only displays number '1' as content. Could anyone point out the error? Here's a code that has the same dilemma with my code.

```
local input = {} 

for line in io.lines 'try.txt' do
    for i =0,2 do
        column = 0
        for n in line:gmatch'%S+' do
            input[column] = 1
            column = column + 1
            if column < 11 then
                input[column] = tonumber(n)
                print("input",input[column],column)
            end
        end
    end

    print("\n")    

    for k = 0, 10 do
        print("-->",input[k],k)
    end

end
```

My 'try.txt' only includes the ff.

```
2 64 124 21.282 128 91 18 97.8 0 0 0 
2 -99 0 0 161 69 -99 97.7 0 0 0 
1 68 195 29.646 162 87 20 98 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Swap these lines:

```
input[column] = 1
column = column + 1
```